# PHPUnit testing ZF2 fail on model

Tags: php, unit-testing, zend-framework, zend-framework2

I am trying to make a simple Unit test over this code:

```
  class IndexController extends CommonController
{  
    public function indexAction()
    {
    $this->layout('layout/layouthome');
    $language = $this->getLanguage($this->params('language'));

    $sm = $this->getServiceLocator();
    $tests = $sm->get('Tests');
    $users = $sm->get('Users');

    $this->layout()->language = substr($language, 0, 2);
    $translations = $this->getTranslations($sm, $language);
    $this->layout()->getAllTranslationByLocale = $translations;

    $userSession = $this->loginService->getSessionUser();

    if (!empty($userSession)) {
        $this->redirectUser($userSession, $language);
    }

    return new ViewModel(array(
        'translations' => $translations,
        'language' => $language,
        'getAllJobsByTopjobs' => $tests->getAllTestsByTopTests(),
        'countAllUsers' => $users->countAllUsers(),
    ));
    }
}
```

and my simple test is like this:

```
<?php namespace ApplicationTest\Controller;

use Zend\Stdlib\ArrayUtils;
use Zend\Test\PHPUnit\Controller\AbstractHttpControllerTestCase;

class LogoutTest extends AbstractHttpControllerTestCase
{
    protected $traceError = true;

    public function setUp()
    {
        parent::setUp();
        $configOverrides = [];

        $this->setApplicationConfig(ArrayUtils::merge(
        // Grabbing the full application configuration:
            include __DIR__ . '/../../../../../config/application.config.php',
            $configOverrides
        ));

    }

    public function testIndexActionCanBeAccessed()
    {
        $this->dispatch('/');
        $this->assertResponseStatusCode(200);
    }
}
```

The issue that I have is I can't instantiate the Tests and Users model. I am new to ZF2 and also to Unit tests, so any help is much appreciated. Thank you

LATER EDIT

adding in the setup() test

```
Bootstrap::getServiceManager();
$this->setApplicationConfig(Bootstrap::getConfig());
```

So now all the config is loading correctly. Thank you Andrew for all the help :)

Comment: Does the code actually work when you trigger the controller in the browser?

Comment: yes, that is the nice part of it. I can't get the Tests model in console somehow, but in the browser all is ok.

Comment: can you post more of your test controller, are you extending a zend test controller? - sometimes you will need to setup the config so it can find your services.

Comment: I added the full test file so you can have a better vision

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll need to see more of the code for your test, but if you're using a zend based phpunit class you'll need to setup your config, an example below:

```
namespace Something;

use Zend\Test\PHPUnit\Controller\AbstractHttpControllerTestCase;

class SomethingTest extends AbstractHttpControllerTestCase
{ 
    public function setUp()
    {
        // now the tests know how to load your config and
        // services / service manager etc.
        // this may be your main config or a test specific config
        $this->setApplicationConfig(
           include __DIR__ . '/../../config/application.config.test.php'
        );
    }

    public function testIndexActionCanBeAccessed()
    {
        // access via application object..
        $bla = $this->getApplication()->getServiceManager()->get('Tests');

        $this->dispatch('/');
        $this->assertResponseStatusCode(200);
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, this is exactly the code that I have in this moment. The difference is that I am using the application.config.php file not a dedicated test file. So it is not working with this code because it it failing on the model call in Controller ($tests = $sm->get('Tests');). The error message is : 

    Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager::get was unable to fetch or create an instance for Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter . In the same time the code works perfectly on browser.

Comment: have you tried this: $this->getApplication()->getServiceManager()->get('Tests');
this will bootstrap the application using the config you provided and allow the sm to find things

Comment: Andrew you got it! :) please upgrade the answer and I will accept it :). PS one more question: All the models are on, the test is parsing the hole method index but I have an error with the message: Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager::get was unable to fetch or create an instance for Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter . This is outside of the question scope so If you want to answer to this also it will be super cool :) Thank you

Comment: And one more request: can you explain a little bit your answer? why do I need to do it like this? I am tying to understand better what is happening there so I can have a clear view over it in the future.

Comment: If you follow that controllers methods (just view the controller it extends) you will see. it needs to bootstrap the full application before it can use the SM

Comment: I've tried to debug it and I don't have a clue of what is happening there. So from what I can tell the IndexController extends AbstractActionController witch extends AbstractController. The AbstractController is implementing Dispatchable, EventManagerAwareInterface, InjectApplicationEventInterface, ServiceLocatorAwareInterface and a looked over them and I can't find relation to the error that i have now: Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager::get was unable to fetch or create an instance for Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter. I realize that I have to import the Zend\Db\Adapter but how to do that? :)

Comment: I advanced a little bit in the way that I added to my test the adapter : $this->adapter = $sm->get('Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter'); but I get another error like: Zend\ServiceManager\Exception\ServiceNotCreatedException: An exception was raised while creating "Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter"; no instance returned and Caused by
PHPUnit_Framework_Error_Notice: Undefined index: db . So the thing is how to get the db in the test? this is loading from the config/global.php right?

Comment: yeah, have you got anything in the config such as array('db' => array(..))

Comment: Yes. I got it finally. I've replace your code with Bootstrap::getServiceManager(); $this->setApplicationConfig(Bootstrap::getConfig()); and now the config is loaded